# Asp.Net Mvc Route - Error Route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am trying to route error Page not found in my application, if any route is wrong then display Error Route.

my default route below

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "NotFound",
    "{*.}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "PageNotFound" }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in web.config File.

```
 <system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error" />
</httpErrors>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

The dot (.) will cause a conflict. use alpha characters for the parameter name,

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

//Catch-All InValid (NotFound) Routes
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NotFound",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "PageNotFound" }
);
```

It would also allow you to get the parameter in the action as well

```
public class ErrorController : Controller {
    public ActionResult PageNotFound(string url) { ... }
}
```

in case you wanted to do anything else with the value. ie logging, audit...etc

Comment: thanks for replay but it's not working,when i run application then i want every time open my default path Home Page, if i open other path like userlist or edit page  then it's go to Page404 view